# Searching for a substring in a string in shell script

Tags: regex, string, shell, sed

I have a very lengthy string (length is also not fixed)
I want to extract a substring lying between 'email' and '@gmail.com'

Suppose it is

```
xhxjcndjcnkjcnd cjkjcdckjncx email:substring@gmail.comjndhcjkdhcnchjdccb djc
```

I want to extract the 'substring'  in the String..
Can I do this using regular expression , using sed tool.?

Comment: Do you have other mail than gmail? If so, solution using gmail as search will no work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/email:(.*?)\@gmail.com/)'
```

Tested below:

```
> echo "xhxjcndjcnkjcnd cjkjcdckjncx email:substring@gmail.comjndhcjkdhcnchjdccb djc" | perl -lne 'print $1 if(/email:(.*?)\@gmail.com/)'
substring
>
```

Answer (score 1):

> VALUE="xhxjcndjcnkjcnd cjkjcdckjncx email:substring@gmail.comjndhcjkdhcnchjdccb djc"
>
> echo $VALUE | awk -F":" '{print $2}' |cut -d@ -f1

Comment: The `sed` just do the same as `awk`, so why not two `awk` like this `awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk -F@ '{print $1}'` or two `sed`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
INPUT="xhxjcndjcnkjcnd cjkjcdckjncx email:substring@gmail.comjndhcjkdhcnchjdccb djc"
USERNAME=$(sed -n "s/.*\email:\(.*\)@gmail\.com.*/\\1/p" <<< $INPUT)
echo $USERNAME
```

Comment: This returns `substring@gmail.com` not correctly `substring`.  You should also change backtics to paranthese `$(data)`  Eksample `MAIL=$(sed -n "s/.*\email:\(.*@gmail\.com\).*/\\1/p" <<< $INPUT)`

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
awk -F":" '{split($2,a,"@");print a[1]}' file
substring
```

It you have many lines to search for gmail addresses

```
awk -F":" '/gmail\.com/ {split($2,a,"@");print a[1]}'
substring
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell can handle this:

```
$ line='xhxjcndjcnkjcnd cjkjcdckjncx email:substring@gmail.comjndhcjkdhcnchjdccb djc'
$ name=${line#*email:}       # remove the prefix ending with "email:"
$ name=${name%@gmail.com*}   # remove the suffix starting with "@gmail.com"
$ echo $name
substring
```

Answer (score 0):

I think grep (with positive lookahead and positive lookbehind) is the correct tool for the job:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=email:).*?(?=@gmail\.com)'<<< "xhxjcndjcnkjcnd cjkjcdckjncx email:substring@gmail.comjndhcjkdhcnchjdccb djc"
substring
```